# For a certain Lie Algebra $L$, show Lie algebra and $\dim L' = \operatorname{rank}(\gamma)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $\gamma \in \operatorname{End}(V)$. Let $L$ have an underlying vector space $V \oplus \operatorname{span}\{x\}$. Show that if we define the Lie bracket on $L$ by $[y,z]=0$ and $[x,y]=\gamma(y)$ for all $z,y \in V$ then $L$ is a Lie algebra and $\dim L'=\operatorname{rank}(\gamma)$.

So I showed that this bilinear operation was constructed in such a way that the Jacobi identity will always hold. I am now left to showing that $\dim L' = \operatorname{rank}(\gamma)$. Now, I feel like I have a very good understanding of why this is true, but I don't know how to turn my idea into a rigorous mathematical proof.

Since $L' = \{[z,y] : z,y \in L\}$, from our construction the only nonzero elements of $L'$ will be of the form $[x,y]$ for $y \in V$. Now, since $[x,y] = \gamma(y)$, we must be close.

So let $\{[x,y_1],....,[x,y_n]\}$ be a basis for $L'$. How do we show that $\{\gamma(y_1),....\gamma(y_n)\}$ span the image of $\gamma$?

Thanks everyone! This website is the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to show that $L' = Im(\gamma)$. Lastly, by the definition of rank, we have that $\dim(L') = \text{rank}(\gamma)$.